# Conditionals in Python list comprehentions

Tags: python, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

```
'urls' : [line for line in post.css('div.text-box a::attr(href)').getall() if line=re.compile('http.*') else pass]
```

I'm trying to extract links for a page of posts IF there are lists, my attempt above doesn't work. What's the right way to write it?

Comment: `line==re.compile('http.*')` perhaps?

Comment: You can't `pass` in a list comprehension. Just get rid of `else pass` and it will still filter the output list to only the items where your condition is true.

Comment: Oh yeah, I missed the point by Devesh. `=` is an assignment, so you'll also need to change that to `==` too for comparison of values. You'll need both suggested changes.

Comment: except for all the other comments, you also forgot to add curly bruckets { }. You are creating a dictionary here.